# I am unable to insert data into database from form

Tags: java

I am trying to create and insert data into database from my app form using databaseHelper in android studio. But I keep getting errors. When I check my logcat this is the code I saw:

> Process: com.mysite.appName, PID: 17995
>                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4725)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4720)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
>                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>                                                                        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "firstName":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table users (id
>   integer primary key not null  firstName text not null, lastName text
>   not null, email text not null, phone text not null, password text not
>   null);
>                                                                           at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                           at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your issue is towards the bottom of the logcat, where it says `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "firstName":`

It then goes on to list the SQL statement that it was not able to compile:

```
create table users (id integer primary key not null firstName text not null, lastName text not null, email text not null, phone text not null, password text not null);
```

It looks like you are missing a comma in your create table statement, immediately after `id integer primary key not null`.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. If you could mark it as the Accepted Answer, that would be great.